# Maven: Custom mojos, goals and phases, how does it fit?

Tags: java, maven

Here is what I understood about Maven's internal model (aka build model):

Maven does have global goals (clean, build, site). Each defines a life-cycle that is also altered by the packaging directive. The life-cycle is composed of phases.

Each maven build process also has a set of plug-ins being active. A plugin can be executed in any phase using the  tag in the plug-in definition of the pom.xml.

Each plugin itself supplies some mojos. Those mojos are actually the goals a plugin provides and may be even used on the command line.

The question is how does it fit together?

The default goal of Maven is build. If I want to add my plugin to the resources:testResources phase what must the @Mojo annotation be and how does the  part of my plug-in's pom representation should look like?

Comment: Here is a list of the phases of the standard lifecycles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference `resources:testResources` is not a phase but a goal (of the resources plugin) bound to the `process-test-resources` phase in some lifecycles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind a MOJO to a default phase, you need to use the [`defaultPhase`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Mojo.html#defaultPhase%28%29) attribute of the `@Mojo` annotation. For example, to bind to the "process test resources" phase, use [`LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_RESOURCES`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/LifecyclePhase.html#PROCESS_TEST_RESOURCES). Note that by default, this default phase is set to none, meaning you have to specify a phase in the POM for your plugin to be executed if `defaultPhase` is not set.

With such a default phase, not specifying a phase in your POM will result in the plugin being executed for that phase.

It is also possible to override that phase, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>...<groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>id</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- force phase to process-resources, whatever the default -->
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```